# JQuery window resize doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question is really bored but i haven't handle it. I need to call an object method when window resized. The code is as shown below

```
    var ThemeDesignerHelper = new function () {
        this.initialize = function () {
            debugger;
            var self = this;
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $(window).resize(function () {
                    alert("res");
                });
            });

        }
        this.initialize();
}
```

Jquery doesn't fire alert when i resized window. I think this is not about jquery or my browser version because when i tried the above code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmwn3f8t/) it works perfectly.  Why does not above code work? Anyone have any opinion to share with me.

Note: When i change window to document it works!

Comment: When is this code executed? Is it before the jQuery library has been included? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: there is no error in console.

Comment: i first included jquery library before above script.

Comment: Are you sure, you didn't forget to disable JS-tracing in console? May be you should remove "debugger;" ? oO

Comment: If i forget to disable js-tracing it must not work on jsfiddle. Am i wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must solve this problem immediately you can use javascript window event listener as below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            if (window.addEventListener) {
                window.addEventListener("resize", function(){alert("res")}, false);
            } else if (object.attachEvent) {
                object.attachEvent("on" + "resize", function(){alert("res")});
            } else {
                console.error("unknown event listener object.");
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks it works! but if you know why jquery doesn't work please inform me!

Comment: i dont know at the moment. But when i will learn about this, I will send answer.

Answer (score 0):

For JQuery, the correct syntax on a window resize is:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
   //Do something
});
```

Comment: Jquery documentation says "As the .resize() method is just a shorthand for .on( "resize", handler ), detaching is possible using .off( "resize" ). "But i have already tried your answer, it doesn;t work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   $('body').prepend('<div>' + $(window).width() + '</div>');
 });
```

Comment: try to use your code inside the function don't use alert

Comment: It doesn't work and why you offer me to prevent use alert.